# Change mysql column type on the fly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, email

Is it possible to change the column type on the fly without altering it?
I have a table with an expire_date column for email users. The type is as follows:

```
ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 365 DAY)
```

So this returns something like this:

```
+---------------------+
| expire_date         |
+---------------------+
| 2015-03-22 13:03:53 |
+---------------------+
```

However, I am trying to send 30-day notices before the email expires with a php script.
My select statement looks like this:

```
select email from new_users where SUBDATE(`expire_date`, INTERVAL 30 DAY) = CURDATE();
```

As you can see, I am consulting the query to check all emails that are within 30 days of the expired_date timestamp. But this wont work because the expire_date timestamp uses the full date and timestamp which I still want to keep. `CURDATE()` uses just the day which is what I need since it would be impossible to run the cron php script based on seconds. The select statement boils down to: if the 30 day notice of the email selected is equal to todays date, then send an email to that user. Like mentioned, expired_date can't match CURDATE() because it includes the actual time. I would like to modify the expired_date column to just display the date for this query. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `date()` function to do what you want:

```
select email
from new_users
where SUBDATE(date(`expire_date`), INTERVAL 30 DAY) = CURDATE();
```

It removes the time portion.

However, a more efficient way to write the query is:

```
select email
from new_users
where expiredate >= adddate(curdate(), interval 30 day) and
      expiredate < adddate(curdate(), interval 31 day);
```

This may seem more complicated.  But, by moving the function call to the "constant" (`CURDATE()`), the SQL engine can use an index on `expiredate`.

Comment: Beautiful! I was trying something similar by using EXTRACT in place of date but then could not figure out how to extract the day. Really appreciate the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

why not use `NOW()`; and compare directly with your column , you dont need to convert to date.

```
select email from new_users 
where SUBDATE(`expire_date`, INTERVAL 30 DAY) = NOW();
```

Or use DATE() ; to your column.

```
 CURDATE() : // 2008-11-11
 NOW()     : // 2008-11-11 12:45:34
 CURTIME() : // 12:45:34
```

Comment: I did try `NOW()` but since this cron runs in daily cron, it may miss that timestamp since it is based all the way down to the second and it would be impractical for a daily cron. The `DATE()` method is more practical since I want only the date portion, therefore the cron can run at any time of the day and it will still work! Thank you both very much for the help.